# "ErrorMessage" : "Requested media type is not allowed, please verify the media type and resubmit the request"

Tags: karate

> "ErrorMessage" : "Requested media type is not allowed, please verify
> the media type and resubmit the request",

By default it is adding in `charset=UTF-8` along with application/x-www-form-urlencoded; header

```
1 > Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

how to avoid `charset=UTF-8` by default

i tried this alsoAnd header charset = null but didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

i did resolved this issue with     * configure charset = null